# resize parent if child has CSS and get child index using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the height the multiple parents dynamically if the child height changes.

There is only one child per parent with z-index style..

This is what I've tried to do based on what I've found

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="z-index:1;"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>

</div>
<br>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" ></div>
    <div class="child2" style="z-index:1;"></div>

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".parent").each(function() {

  var divIndex = ;
  var divHeight = ;  

  if ($('this').children().css('z-index') == '1')
{
   // Get height and index of the single specific element with z-index css 
}

$('this').resize();
    $('this').delegate();


});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/EgbLk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code was riddled with javascript errors, more specifically the use of $('this'), take out the single quotes: $(this);

Most of your CSS won't style due to the use of id's instead of classes.

Here is an updated jsfiddle that corrected the errors and will get you on the right track for iterating the parents child divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/EgbLk/4/

```
$('.parent').children().each(
    function(){

      var divIndex = null ;
      var divHeight = null ;          

      if($(this).css('z-index') === '1') {
         alert('z-index is 1'); 
      }

      $(this).parent().resize();
      $(this).parent().delegate();      
    }
);
```

Here is some "corrected" CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#ff0000;
}

.child2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height:20px
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height:50px
        z-index:1;
}

.child3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height:100px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```
$('.parent').children().filter(function() {
        return this.style.zIndex==='1';
    }).each(function(index, elem) {
        var divIndex=$(elem).index(),
            divHeight=$(elem).css('height');
        $(elem).resize();
        $(elem).delegate();
});​
```

In your fiddle none of the elements with z-index=1 has a height.
No idea what the resize and delegate functions do, but I assume they are functions you are using for something.

To resize the parent ".parent" element to the same height as the element with z-index=1 dynamically on resize you could just do:

```
$('.parent').children().filter(function() {
        return this.style.zIndex==='1';
    }).each(function(index, elem) {
        var divIndex=$(elem).index(),
            divHeight=$(elem).css('height');
        $(elem).on('resize', function() {
            $(this).closest('.parent').css('height', $(this).height());
        });
});​
```